# Getting 'help()' text in non-interactive manner (Python)

Tags: python

I'd like to get `help(obj)` text in IPython or Jupyter notebook in a non-interactive manner, into some variable instead of it being displayed.

Note: `help` provides more information than `obj.__doc__` provides, so that's not quite an alternative.

Comment: Please note that the function "is intended for interactive use." per [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#help).

Comment: @ywbaek I'm sure we've all used technology only in a manner intended (predicted) by the authors and not according to the domain and the problem at hand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Short answer:

```
import pydoc
help_result_string = pydoc.render_doc(obj)
```

## Longer answer:

When you call `help(obj)`, it is a wrapper to `pydoc.help(obj)` (see `help.__doc__`), which is the same as `pydoc.Helper()(obj)` (from pydoc source: `help = Helper()`), which usually leads to `pydoc.doc(obj)`, which writes the resulting string from `pydoc.render_doc(obj)` to the standard output or a pager, depending on the system.

Details on what other things can happen when `help(obj)` is called can be found in the [pydoc source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/pydoc.py).